# How can I dim my monitor?

Tags: brightness, monitor

On windows, I had an application called [dimmer](http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/). I used it on my desktop monitor to make the brightness more manageable. I want an equivalent for Ubuntu. I tried xbacklight to no avail.

Comment: Try http://jonls.dk/redshift/ --- I didn't use it, but its equivalent for android (twilight) is a must-have IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laptop, press function key(Fn) and press left arrow(<-)key to lower the brightness of your screen

Comment: I'm using a desktop monitor, not a laptop.